# Linux, ubuntu 18.04 ,Yolov4 darknet ,Video stream stopped! (on my pc, not google colab)

Tags: opencv, video-streaming, darknet

i have just installed darknet for yolov4. It works alright on images. However, when i tried this:

```
./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights test50.mp4 -i 0 -thresh 0.25
```

I got:

```
video stream stopped! (infinite loop)
```

Information about pc:

```
CUDA 10.0
CUDNN 7.6.5
OPENCV 4.5.1
```

On the makefile:

```
    GPU=1
    CUDNN=1
    CUDNN_HALF=1
    OPENCV=1
    AVX=0
    OPENMP=0
    LIBS0=0
    ZED_CAMERA=0
ZED_CAMERA_v2_8=0
```

What am i not doing correctly? Is it due to the opencv? Thanks for taking the time to read this post!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I use Mac Big Sur. To build the repo, I used "./build.sh". This worked without issue. Then I downloaded pre-trained weights (instructions are given on the GitHub repo). I tried the demo with the laptop webcam, this command worked for me.

```
./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights -i 0 -thresh 0.25
```

For the video input experiment, I used this command to run the inference on a video.

```
./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights "video_path"
```

This command worked for me. I tried with yolov4-tiny.weights and it was not bad on laptop cpu. I hope this information work for you.